# Google Sheets API v4 share

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

My Webapp is creating, writing and reading google sheets perfectly.

But I cannot find anything in the documentation about how to share the newly
created document. I need to be able to give editing access to other individuals.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing) (rather than a Sheets API) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create permission and can share with any  other  user.  Below is the code snippet.

```
 var body = {
      'type': 'user',
      'role': 'reader',// reader/writer/organzier
      'emailAddress': 'xyz@gmail.com'
    };

    var drive=google.drive({version: 'v3',auth});

    drive.permissions.create({
      'fileId': "SheetId",  //sheetID returned from create sheet response
      'resource': body,
    }, function(err, response) {if (err) {
      console.error('error-------', err);
      return;
      } else{
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))) ;
      }
    });
```